# drf-yasg - testproj - how to silent all the debug output

Tags: django, debugging, drf-yasg

How can I silent the debug statements for drf-yasg - testproj ?
https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg

This is how I set it up:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg.git
$ cd drf-yasg
$ virtualenv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ cd testproj
(venv) $ python -m pip install -U pip setuptools
(venv) $ pip install -U -r requirements.txt
(venv) $ python manage.py migrate
(venv) $ python manage.py runserver
(venv) $ firefox localhost:8000/swagger/
```

But it keeps producing a lot of debug prints which makes it difficult for me test certain features. How do I silent these debug prints ? Thanks.

Here are the debug prints:

```
2019-09-14 08:02:10,769 | DEBUG | django.utils.autoreload | File /Users/axil/Documents/project/unrealpower/unrealpower_upgrade_v2/testdrf/drvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/coreapi/exceptions.py first seen with mtime 1568447198.368635
2019-09-14 08:02:10,769 | DEBUG | django.utils.autoreload | File /Users/axil/Documents/project/unrealpower/unrealpower_upgrade_v2/testdrf/drvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py first seen with mtime 1568447200.446008
2019-09-14 08:02:10,769 | DEBUG | django.utils.autoreload | File /Users/axil/Documents/project/unrealpower/unrealpower_upgrade_v2/testdrf/drvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/certs.py first seen with mtime 1568447203.023515
2019-09-14 08:02:10,769 | DEBUG | django.utils.autoreload | File /Users/axil/Documents/project/unrealpower/unrealpower_upgrade_v2/testdrf/drvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/coreapi/compat.py first seen with mtime 1568447198.368073
2019-09-14 08:02:10,770 | DEBUG | django.utils.autoreload | File /Users/axil/Documents/project/unrealpower/unrealpower_upgrade_v2/testdrf/drvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/model_meta.py first seen with mtime 1568447200.529353
2019-09-14 08:02:10,770 | DEBUG | django.utils.autoreload | File /Users/axil/Documents/project/unrealpower/unrealpower_upgrade_v2/testdrf/drvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py first seen with mtime 1568447201.356465
2019-09-14 08:02:10,770 | DEBUG | django.utils.autoreload | File /Users/axil/Documents/project/unrealpower/unrealpower_upgrade_v2/testdrf/drvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py first seen with mtime 1568447200.446478
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logging settings are configured for this test project in `testproj/testproj/settings/base.py` file. Change log level to `INFO` for `drf_yasg`  and django package there. like this

```
   'drf_yasg': {
        'handlers': ['console_log'],
        'level': 'INFO',
        'propagate': False,
    },

    'django': {
        'handlers': ['console_log'],
        'level': 'INFO',
        'propagate': False,
    }
```